# Falsely duplicate question on stackoverflow

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I asked this question in stackoverflow and it was marked as a duplicate, which made sense, I guess I should 've mentioned I had already looked at that answer and it didn't help. I edited the question to make amends however it still is marked as duplicate....

What should I do, I don't think it will ever get answered if it is a duplicate? Currently my plan of action is to wait another day and then just ask it again as a different question although I feel that is not good practice.

thanks

[installed cvxpy, i can import but doesn't autocomplete in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291340/installed-cvxpy-i-can-import-but-doesnt-autocomplete-in-ipython)

Comment: Question is now reopened.

Comment: Anyone else find it hilarious that this question was falsely marked as duplicate? This is meta even for meta.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally if one of your questions gets closed as duplicate and you don't agree with that then you can

1. edit your question to signify the difference to the duplicate
2. if your question does not get reopened within a reasonable time, you can flag for moderator attention and ask for reopening

#### Never just reask a question! Improve existing questions.

Comment: how do I flag it for a moderator? And yes I agree with you which is why I turned to asking a question here!

Comment: See the *flag* link under the question tags? Click there, choose *other* and explain your request.